# How to quickly transform from RGB24 to BGRA on iOS?

Tags: ios, time, transform, rgb, rgba

which I use is `vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888` and `vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888`. First change it from RGB24 to ARGB, because OPENGL ES doesn't support ARGB, so need to change ARGB to BGRA with `vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888`. But when the data need to change is big the time cost is high, so someone with better methods? thanks! My codes like this:

```
- (void)transformRGBToBGRA:(const UInt8 *)pict{
rgb.data = (void *)pict;

vImage_Error error = vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888(&rgb,NULL,0,&argb,NO,kvImageNoFlags);
if (error != kvImageNoError) {
    NSLog(@"vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888 error");
}

const uint8_t permuteMap[4] = {3,2,1,0};

error = vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(&argb,&bgra,permuteMap,kvImageNoFlags);
if (error != kvImageNoError) {
    NSLog(@"vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888 error");
}

free((void *)pict);

}
```

Comment: You already posted this and got one answer with 4 up ticks = why are you posting it again? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11683864/96716

Comment: Because I think they are different, one is BGR , the other is BGRA, they need different memory capacity. So I want to know whether APPLE have more simple api to finish this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found the fastest solution is assembly. Just like this:

```
__asm__ volatile(
                 "0:                \n"
                 "# load 3 64-bit regs with interleave: \n"
                 "vld3.8      {d0,d1,d2}, [%0]!   \n"
                 "# swap d0 and d2 - R and B\n"
                 "vswp d0, d2   \n"
                 "# store 4 64-bit regs: \n"
                 "vst4.8      {d0,d1,d2,d3}, [%2]!      \n"
                 "subs        %1, %1, #1       \n"
                 "bne         0b            \n"
                 :
                 : "r"(img), "r"(numPixels24), "+r"(bgraData)
                 : "r6", "r7","r8"
                 );
```